# Can Scala Build Tool (sbt) authenticate to a artifacts repository using SPNEGO?

Tags: sbt, spnego

We have an internal Nexus artifacts repository which we authenticate against using either HTTP Basic Auth, or SPNEGO (i.e Kerberos)

With sbt 0.13, artifacts downloads and uploads could happen automatically if the user had a valid Kerberos ticket. But since sbt 1.0, it no longer works out of the box. I suspect this is due to the use of [Gigahorse](https://github.com/eed3si9n/gigahorse)

Can sbt 1.0+ be configured to do SPNEGO authentication? Gigahorse itself seems to support it.